# Memory Movies in Photos app for Mac

Tags: photos, photos.app

The iPhone has a great "Memory Movie" feature that that assembles pictures and videos of one person into a little music video.

Can you do that on the Photos app too? I could only find the slideshow, which isn't the same thing. For instance it doesn't play the "live photo" videos, it just shows stills.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not possible according to the Apple pagE: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207023